# Sorting li items in order of Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html-lists

If I have an unordered list:

```
<ul>
 <li data-sort-name="a">A</li>
 <li data-sort-name="d">D</li>
 <li data-sort-name="b">B</li>
 <li data-sort-name="c">C</li>
</ul>
```

and an array:

```
[a,b,c,d]
```

Is there a way to sort the above list in the same order as the array. (Array isn't always chronological, that's just for explanation purposes).

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

One possible jQuery solution:

```
$.each(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], function(i, v) {
    $('li[data-sort-name="' + v + '"]').appendTo('ul');
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8FR8V/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a library like underscore for functionality like that. They're small, fast, and very useful!

Underscore sorting functionality: http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy